# Dialog with flexible height

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dialog, widget

I am trying to get myself a dialog with flutter.

1. needs to be screen wide
2. it needs to be semi-transparent
3. it should blur its background
4. it should be barrier dismiss-able
5. it needs to have screen wide top/down border
6. its height should be flexible

The problem is; I got all of them done except the last one, my dialog is fixed size. the following is the simplified, minimal version of it.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: ''),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void popup() {
    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 0.2,
            widthFactor: 1.0,
            child: ClipRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                  child: Container(
                      //color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(9),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(10),
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text("SIMPLE TEXT"),
                        ],
                      ))),
            ));
      },
      barrierDismissible: true, // Allows tapping outside to dismiss
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      transitionBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("THIS IS A BACKGROUND TEXT"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: popup,
        tooltip: 'POPUP',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `FractionallySizedBox` with [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html).

```dart
return FittedBox(
    child: ClipRect(
      // ...
));
```

---

See also: [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)